# c++ error: debug assertion failed

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging, vector, runtime-error

I am trying to run this program on visual studio 2010 Pro.
I can compile it successfully but when I run the programm I get The following error:

Debug Assertion Failed!
Expression: Vector subscript out of range.

in this simple programme I am trying to compute the maximum sum of consecutif non nul numbers in a vector of integers.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
int somme(vector<int> tab);

int main() {
vector<int> tab;
tab[0] = 2;
tab[1] = 3;
tab[2] = 0;
tab[3] = 0;
tab[4] = 4;
cout <<somme_consecutifs_max(tab) << endl;
return 0;
}

 int somme(vector<int> tab){
int sum(0);
int max(0);
for (int i = 0; i < tab.size(); ++i){
    if(tab[i] != 0) {
        sum += tab[i];
    }
    else{
        if(sum > max){
            max = sum;
        }
        sum = 0;
    }

}
    return max;
}
```

on the other hand, why do I cannot initialize my vector of int in Visual Studio 2010 in this why:

```
vector<int> tab = {1, 2, 0, 0, 3};
```

Answer (score 3):

When you do this

```
vector<int> tab;
```

you initialize a size 0 vector, which you immediately access out of bounds. You need

```
vector<int> tab(5);
```

to make a size-5 vector. Alternatively, you can push elements back into the vector, increasing the size by one each time.

```
vector<int> tab;
tab.push_back(2);
tab.push_back(3);
....
```

Comment: thank you very much, what about initialization of vectors in VS2010 using `vector<int> tab = {1, 2, 0, 0, 3};` why this is not possible ?

Comment: @GambaOsaca I don't know anything about VS2010 (or any VS for that matter), but that is C++11 syntax, and it is unlikely that version of VS supports it.